# i cannot locate this problem keep getting mysql syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, netbeans

```
String sql="insert into std(StudentID,Surname,Name,CourseCode,Maths,English,Physics,Biology,Chemistry,Psychology,HealthScience,Religion"+"TotalScore,Average,Ranking)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";`
       ` try{
           `pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);`
           `pst.setString`(1, jTextField14.getText());`
          ` pst.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());`
          ` pst.setString(3, jTextField2.getText());`
          ` pst.setString(4,(String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());`
          ` pst.setString(5, jTextField6.getText());`
           `pst.setString(6, jTextField7 .getText());`
          ` pst.setString(7, jTextField8.getText());`
          ` pst.setString(8, jTextField9.getText());`
           `pst.setString(9, jTextField10.getText());`
           `pst.setString(10, jTextField11.getText());`
          ` pst.setString(11, jTextField12.getText());`
          ` pst.setString(12, jTextField13.getText());`
           `pst.setString(13, jTextField3.getText());`
           `pst.setString(14, jTextField4.getText());`
          ` pst.setString(15, jTextField5.getText());`

           `pst.execute();`
           `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "system update completed");`
           `rs.close();`
          ` pst.close();`
       `}catch(Exception e){`
            `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);`
       ` }`
  `  } `
```

i keep getting this error error in sql syntax check for error that corresponds to mysql manual near

Comment: `Religion"+"TotalScore,` should be `Religion, TotalScore`. Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: It still gives error when i remove the +

Comment: You would - at least - need to show us the entire error message (please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59795579/edit) your question to add that important piece of information).

Comment: Note that a database table is not a spreadsheet. Rapidly consider revising your schema

Comment: *"It still gives error when i remove the `+`"* - Yes.  If you *just* remove the `+`.  Look at what GMB wrote more carefully.

Comment: Thanks guys..i solved it..the problem was from my table name

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Although the error message is missing, it's probably in consequence of calling an incompatible setter method for one or more parameters.

For example, an id column is usually a number. Hence, based on the data type of this column, you have to call the corresponding setter method (setInt, setLong).

To get more information about PreparedStatements and its methods, read this document:
[docs.oracle.com:PreparedStatement.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: Calling an 'incompatible setter method' (whatever you mean with that) should not cause a syntax error.